# How to rotate a QPixmap without changing size

Tags: qt, qpixmap

How to rotate a QPixmap without changing size
I use this code but when I rotate the image it change the size of the image.

The header file

```
#ifndef CUSTOMDIAL_H
#define CUSTOMDIAL_H
#include <QDial>
class CustomDial : public QDial
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
CustomDial(QWidget * parent = nullptr);
private:
virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) override;
};
#endif
```

the CPP file

```
#include "Customdial.h"
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QColor>
#include <QPixmap>
 CustomDial::CustomDial(QWidget* parent)
                    : QDial(parent)
 {
// Default range
QDial::setRange(0,100);
}   
void CustomDial::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
int a = QDial::sliderPosition();
QPainter painter(this);
//load pixmap
QPixmap pix(":/img/img/knob.png");
//rotate pixmap
QMatrix rm;
        rm.rotate(a);
        pix = pix.transformed(rm);
//draw pixmap
painter.drawPixmap(QPointF(0,0),
                    pix.scaled(QDial::height(),
                    QDial::height(),
                    Qt::KeepAspectRatio),
                    pix.rect().adjusted(1, 1, -1000, -1000) );
}
```

How to rotate a QPixmap without changing size I use this code but when I rotate the image it change the size of the image the header file

Comment: What do you mean, explain yourself better, you could place an image of what you get and what you want to obtain.

Comment: I Just made a custom class for QDial to support stylesheets for adding background images now my problem is that when you rotate the image in the dialer with this code it change the size of the image , is there another way to rotate a Qpixmap ?

Comment: Show your code, to test your code and see how it can be fixed.

Comment: here is my code ,and I use a png rotary button for resourse

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your question, you can just use QPixmap::copy() to extract the central part of the needed size:

```
//load pixmap
QPixmap pix(":/images/pixmap.png");
//rotate pixmap
QMatrix rm;
rm.rotate(a);
int pxw = pix.width(), pxh = pix.height();
pix = pix.transformed(rm);
pix = pix.copy((pix.width() - pxw)/2, (pix.height() - pxh)/2, pxw, pxh);
```

But that would be inefficient (see also note for [QPixmap::transformed()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#transformed)). I would prefer drawing directly using QPainter without creating intermediary pixmaps especially because you already have it:

```
qreal scale = qMin(width(), height()) / qMax(pix.width(), pix.height());
QPointF center(width() / 2., height() / 2.); // widget center
// uncomment to trade performance for quality
//  painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
painter.translate(center);
painter.rotate(degrees);
painter.scale(scale, scale);
painter.drawPixmap(-pix.rect().center(), pix);
```

Also consider loading QPixmap on initialization of your widget and storing it rather that doing it in paintEvent (again for the sake of efficiency).

The reason that QPixmap::transformed() increases the size on rotation is to get the whole image including the edges because you can always extract a smaller image from the bigger one but not vice versa. You probably have a round picture but for rectangular it's immediately obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The method that Qdial is using to calculate the background circle is this

```
int width = option.rect.width();
int height = option.rect.height();
qreal r2 = qMin(width, height) / 2;
r2 -= r2/50;
const qreal d_ = r2 / 6;
const qreal dx = option.rect.x() + d_ + (width - 2 * r2) / 2 + 1;
const qreal dy = option.rect.y() + d_ + (height - 2 * r2) / 2 + 1;
QRectF br = QRectF(dx + 0.5, dy + 0.5,
               int(r2 * 2 - 2 * d_ - 2),
               int(r2 * 2 - 2 * d_ - 2));
```

So `QRect br` is the rect for the background circle. Then just add the Pixmap resource file using those cordinates

```
 int w=option.rect.width()/2;
 int h=option.rect.height()/2;
 painter.translate(w,h);
 painter.rotate(a);

 //draw pixmap
 painter.drawPixmap(-br.width()/2,
                    -br.height()/2,
                         pix.scaled(br.width(),br.height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
```

And you get a perfect resizable and rotatable image inside your dial