# Spinning label in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I want to make a loading animation in Qt C++, the idea is putting a pixmap into the picture label and update the spinning angle, all the code are in mainwindow.cpp, here's the code:
Update rotation:

```
void MainWindow::updateRotation() {
    if (spinning) {
        rotationAngle += 10;
        if (rotationAngle >= 360) {
            rotationAngle = 0;
        }
        QPixmap originalPixmap("D:/Vector3.png"); // Replace with the path to your spinner image

        // Set the desired size for the pixmap
        QSize newSize(151, 151); // Adjust the size based on your preference

        // Scale the original pixmap to the desired size
        QPixmap scaledPixmap = originalPixmap.scaled(newSize, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

        // Create a QTransform for the rotation
        QTransform transform;
        transform.rotate(rotationAngle);

        // Apply the transformation to the pixmap
        QPixmap rotatedPixmap = scaledPixmap.transformed(transform, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
        ui->label_161->setPixmap(rotatedPixmap);
    }
}
```

Start Spinning:

```
void MainWindow::startSpinning()
{
    spinning = !spinning;
    if (spinning) {
        // Start the spinning timer when the button is clicked
        timer->start(50); // Adjust the interval based on your preference
    }
}
```

I load the picture and pixmap in the constructor of the mainwindow class:

```
    QPixmap originalPixmap("D:/Vector3.png");
    QSize newSize(151, 151);
    QPixmap initialPixmap = originalPixmap.scaled(newSize, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    ui->label_161->setPixmap(initialPixmap);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::updateRotation);
```

I have a button and when click it will start the animation:

```
void MainWindow::on_button_clicked()
{
    startSpinning();
}
```

The label pixmap has spinned around, but it keeps moving left and right when spinning:

[image]

I think it has something to do with the coordinates of the pixmap or the label, but i can't find out where

Comment: As you see, the rotation modify the position of your `QPixmap`. So you should: 1) save its position before the rotation, 2) apply the rotation, 3) get the new position, 4) calculate the offset between both positions and finally 5) apply this offset to the `QPixmap` position. Offset is something like `pos_final - pos_initial`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate a QPixmap without changing size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47612117/how-to-rotate-a-qpixmap-without-changing-size)

Comment: The [`transformed()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#transformed) explains it: "the pixmap produced is the smallest pixmap that contains all the transformed points of the original pixmap"; if you substitute the circle with a square and you'll understand what's going on. Using QLabel for this is almost always pointless, use a standard QWidget and implement the drawing in the paint event by using a proper transformation (remember if you want to rotate around the center, you must *first* translate to the center, and *then* rotate).